# Anyone having problems creating a scratch org / promoting a package version today (Aug 12, 2020)? I seem to be getting Winter '21 orgs!

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, second-generation-packaging, winter21

Sorry upfront as this is going to be a bit of a rambling question.

Today I was creating a package using 2nd Generation packaging and as part of my process I install the new package into a test scratch org to see that it installs smoothly.  I noticed that the install process seemed to be taking much longer than usual, so I opened up the scratch org and wanted to look around.  Clicking on the Service app, I noticed the logo was this:

[image: Astro Winter '21]

This is usually bad news, as all my packages that I will create / promote could also be on Winter '21 as well.

I tried to install the package that I promoted today into a normal Salesforce org, and I got a "Mismatching Versions" error, which I believe is the error we get when our packaging / dev orgs are ahead of our client orgs.

My DevHub org is still on Summer '20, so I think it's just the packaging process that's been affected.  I'm not sure if I possibly have a plugin that's messing up, but this is what I see when I run a `sfdx plugins`

```
salesforcedx 49.5.0
├─ salesforcedx-templates 49.2.0
├─ custom-metadata 1.0.8
├─ @salesforce/sfdx-plugin-lwc-test 0.1.7
└─ salesforce-alm 49.5.0
```

I tried to add a `"release":"previous"` entry into my Scratch org config file, but I get an error

```
At this time, we are outside of the preview period. You can create only current release scratch orgs.
```

**Anyone else experiencing this, and hopefully know of a work around?**

To be clear, it seems I'm getting Winter '21 orgs today, when I shouldn't be able to.  **Is there any way to force sfdx to use Summer '20 in both org creation and, more importantly, *package creation*?**

Comment: Please raise a case with salesforce support! Sounds like a bug in the packaging commands!

Comment: Its been reproducible by salesforce.org and other teams. The packaging request is routed to cs46! Sounds like a bug!

Comment: This is not an official response, but we (.org) think it's fixed now. If you continue to get cs46 orgs, definitely open a case.

Comment: I have opened a bug with Salesforce.  Thanks for the input @MohithShrivastava.

Comment: And Thanks @DavidReed, i'll give it a try and report back!

Comment: Things seem to be back to normal!  Thanks @DavidReed

Answer (score 4):

This was a bug that Salesforce corrected.